# How to make checkbox visible when main checkbox checked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

good morning guys,
I have 3 checkboxes created in php. one that i want to use as a controller

```
<p>
    <?php  $creates = array('name'=> 'single_obs_value','class' => 'singleobsyes','value'=> '1','style'=>' float: left; margin-right: 2px;'); ?>
    <?=form_label('Single Observation : ');?>
    <?=form_checkbox($creates);?>
    <br>
</p>
```

And the other two are brought in from a database array variable.

```
<p>
    <?php   foreach($obsnames as $cp){  ?>
        <?php  $create = array('name'=> 'cms_permissions[]','class' => 'singleobs','value'=> $cp->id,'style'=>' float: left; margin-right: 10px;'); ?>
        <span style="width:200px; float:left">
            <?=form_checkbox($create ).' '.form_label($cp->field_name);?>
        </span>
    <?php }  ?>
</p>
```

How do i first make the two brought in by the database invisible when the page loads. Then when the controller checkbox is ticked make the two checkboxes visible again. If possible with a jquery function that uses the class of the controller checkbox as such.

```
$('#singleobsyes').change(function(){
```

Rather than

```
$('input[type="checkbox"']
```

As i use other checkboxes on the page and i believe that may cause some conflict.

Comment: I think you need `$('.singleobsyes')` instead of `$('#singleobsyes')` as _singleobsyes_ is a class

Comment: you can do it with css using proper selectors and sudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('.singleobsyes').hide();// hide all checkboxes other than controller

  $('.singleobsyes').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked') 
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('.singleobsyes').show();    
    else
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('.singleobsyes').hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: _singleobsyes_ is a class hence use class selector

Answer (score 1):

**update**: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPEXA/4/)

you can also do this with css selectors as

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="singleobsyes" name="a"/>check to show others
<input type="checkbox" class="singleobs" name="b"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="singleobs" name="c"/>
```

**css**

```
.singleobs{
    display:none;
}
.singleobsyes:checked ~ .singleobs{
    display:block !important;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPEXA/1/)

you can use wrapper too

[fiddle v2](http://jsfiddle.net/yPEXA/2/)

Answer (score 0):

To make the checkboxes invisible you can `style="display:none"`

Now you can put on the "main" check box an `onchange="showem();"` attribute.

```
function showem()
{
$('#checkbox1id').toggle();
$('#checkbox2id').toggle();
}
```

EDIT: Changes `show` to `toogle`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple this way,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('.singleobsyes').hide();

     $('.singleobsyes').on("change", function(){  
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('.singleobsyes').toggle();            
     });   
});
```